# how to create a webservice in drupal accessible by anyone i.e. anonymous users?

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal, web

I have created a webservice using services module and creating a resource in drupal 7 which is accessible by an anonymous users or publicly by any user. Currently only logged in users can access it, but I want any one to use this webservice using REST webservice.

Comment: do anything like fetching data from records, authenticating users, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You have to give appropriate permissions for the anonymous users to use the web service. For ex, If you want node create to happen by anonymous users then give user permissions for anonymous users.

With respect to authentication, you can disable it as it is open for all.